# gpresult command in Windows 10 insider build 14965.1001

Tags: windows, windows-10, group-policy, windows-insider

I have started testing Windows 10 Insider build 14965.1001 and today I came across this.

[image]

Running *gpresult* command with any switch causes this and closing it doesn't do anything but **ERROR:** on next line.

Is this only with me or is there something wrong with the build ?

*Group policies do work fine and *gpupdate* works fine as well.

Update :

1. `SFC /SCANNOW` didn't find any violations
2. `dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth` completed successfully but still getting the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been resolved after installing latest **Build 15042.0**

I can run `gpresult /v` with no issues now

Answer (score 0):

I think there's some files corrupted try adding the latest admx files or maybe try use sfc /scannow it will surely fix that if not report back .

Comment: I've ran `sfc /scannow` & `dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth` but still getting the same error

Comment: Can you try to move the computer to an OU with no group policies applied to and run gpupdate /force then restart the machine and re run that ? At least we'll know if it's on computer level or not .

Comment: . Plus did you install any ADMX files ? And not to mention if everything fails try re running through your newly installed updates maybe one of them is causing it.

Comment: I don't administer AD at work so can't move it a different OU. I will try to remove it from domain and check it some other day. No ADMX files installed. But system is upto date

Comment: I meant by uninstalling newly installed updates one by one of everything fails new updates can cause it sometimes .

Comment: That is too much work for something that is not affecting my work.

Comment: Yes it's just a theory if everything else fails.

Comment: Any follow up on the issue ?

Comment: As I said it is not affecting my daily usage, I haven't looked more into it. Will wait for a new answer though